# How Google Play maintains the device list?

Tags: android, device

I wonder if anyone knows about how Google play maintains the device list?

This is my case:

We are developing a NFC APP which at the beginning it will work with only about 10 handsets, we really want to limit and filter by handset model (not only by the manifest).

We want to do this through the Google Play's device manager list, however I would like to know this list is maintained, in principle we would like to use the TAC value to identify each handset, but I don't think GP use TAC as ID.

I have doing some testing, I can see there e.g several Samsung S4s, do you know why is that? and even if I allow all of them in the Developer console, then when I try to download the APP, I get the error, "your device is not compatible".

Comment: There are multiple versions of most smartphones, not just the Samsung Galaxy S4. For different markets devices are altered, for example in Europe different frequencies are used for the mobile networks than in America so different hardware is required to connect to those networks. But Samsung is also using different processors for different markets - don't ask me why. But in Europe we get the Snapdragon processors while in America Samsung sticks with its own Exynos processors.

Comment: "however I would like to know this list is maintained" -- I am not aware that this information is publicly available.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of smartphones have different variations, for various countries, network providers etc. If you update the playstore to allow/block a device from installing the app it can take a couple of hours to propogate across there servers.

How the list is maintained I don't know, I would assume that when a device is activated onto Google Play, it likely stores the information within the Play Store device listing. Failing that, the OEM sends the information to Google while they are getting approved for Google Play Services. This is only a guess though, I would guess there is no information actually explaining how this list is maintained as developers do not normally need to know.